# free_pi_tree error with gfortran

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I get a weird error when I attempt to compile some code I'm writing. I have several Fortran modules that I use for linear algebra computations; I don't want to make an application have to use all of them, so I wrote a wrapper module around them:

```
module linear_algebra_mod
    use sparse_matrix_mod
    use csr_matrix_mod
    (etc.)
```

so that the end user can write `use linear_algebra_mod` to get all of them. However, I get the following error when I compile the linear algebra module:

```
gfortran -c sparse_matrix_mod.f90
gfortran -c csr_matrix_mod.f90
gfortran -c linear_algebra_mod.f90
linear_algebra_mod.f90:5.8:

use csr_matrix_mod
    1
Internal Error at (1):
free_pi_tree(): Unresolved fixup
```

This was brought up in bug reports [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47546) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53015) but I wasn't able to glean from those what I should do.

To muddy the waters even further, when I instead use the csr_matrix module first, like so:

```
module linear_algebra_mod
    use csr_matrix_mod
    use sparse_matrix_mod
```

the error disappears.

In case this background information is helpful: the sparse_matrix module defines an abstract data type which the csr_matrix module extends and actually implements.

Answer (score 2):

Internal compiler errors are always an indication of a bug in the compiler. Check if you have the latest version of the compiler, and if you do, file a bug report (you may have a look at the open bugs section to see if it has been reported by someone else already, but it is better to have a bug reported twice than to have one not reported at all, so don't worry too much about possibly filing a duplicate bug report).